# How to search thousands of objects in S3 with Boto3 knowing just a partial key name (not prefix)?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

I have an S3 bucket with roughly 10,000 objects in it. All objects share a similar naming pattern, except for the very end of the name. For example, a file has this pattern:

"Order_RandomValuesHere_UniqueIDHere.txt"

So, all files start with the word Order, followed by random data, and END with an ID value which I want to search on. I am trying to create a Python Lambda script that will take an ID as input parameter, and then search in S3 for the specific object that has this ID value in the name of the object, and pull back data from that object.

```
objectlist = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket="My-Bucket", Prefix="OrderNumber")
```

The above works great to grab everything, assuming I have less than 1000 results. Then, I iterate through the keys looking for my ID in the Key, since the prefix parameter doesn't narrow down my list:

```
 for _ in range(len(objectlist['Contents'])):
    if myId in objectlist['Contents'][_]['Key']:
        print("We have found our Order file! It's key is: " + objectlist['Contents'][_]['Key'])
```

However, the problem is that the list_objects_v2 method (and original list_objects) only returns the first 1000 results. How can I have my lambda function query against the entire 10,000+ results looking for the one file I know is there? (but just don't know full file name or unique prefix). The above works fine if your bucket contains less than 1000 objects.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated! I know there is probably a different way to think about this problem but I'm running into mental roadblocks here...

Thanks!

Comment: you need to use pagination. if there are more than 1000 items it will return you the key you need to feed to your subsequent request to pick up where you left off. the request should return `NextContinuationToken` which you will use for the next request and so forth

Comment: Thanks so much @gold_cy! Totally glossed over that piece when I read the documentation. I knew there had to be an easy solution here!

Comment: You can alternatively also use a [paginator](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/paginators.html).